# Rest COM port after "Bad File number"

Tags: linux, serial-port, lazarus

Is it possible to reset a COM port after it gives an "Bad file number" error.

I'm using my raspberry to communicate with external devices (currently I'm testing a GPS receiver). I'm writing my program in Lazarus and use synaser for the COM-port communication (http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/synaser.TBlockSerial.html). However I would also like to use the solution on a windows computer.

It happens that my program doesn't close the COM-port. When I try to access the port after such an instance it gives me an error: "Bad file number". And it seems that the only possibility to fix this error is to restart the device.

I would like to be able to reset the com-port without restarting.

Comment: Wouldn't it be a better solution to make your program close the COM port? What have you tried?

Comment: Your tag is linux, but the text suggests the problem is on windows?!?! Are you sure the application has shut down entirely ? (that should close handles)

Comment: I can close the COM port in the program, however when the program doesn't close properly the COM port remains open (During development it crashes). I have tried to reinitialize the COM port, but I can'r open or reset it because of the above mentioend error

Comment: And at this point it is a linux problem. I added the comment about the windows computer to make it more general: I'm guess that the solution would also be applicable on a windows platform.